# STM32 - Timer Update Interrupt not working

Tags: timer, interrupt, stm32

I use timer 6 in STM32F7 to generate a clock signal. The problem is I got the same clock frequency (10 kHz) no matter what value I used for the auto-reload register. The AHPB clock is 8 MHz. Here are the initialize function and the interrupt callback:

```
static void MX_TIM7_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  htim7.Instance = TIM7;
  htim7.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim7.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim7.Init.Period = 124;
  htim7.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim7, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

    void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
    if (htim->Instance == TIM7){
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin);
    } 
}
```

In main I call HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim7); before entering the empty while loop. The output I got at LED_Pin is at 10 kHz no matter how I changed the ARR value. When I run the debugger, the UIF flag in SR register was not cleared in the IRQ Handler although  __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE); is called. Does anyone know what the problem is? Did I miss something when setting up the timer?

Comment: "no matter how I changed the ARR value" How do you do that ? In your code the ARR is set by `htim7.Init.Period = 124;`Do you change this hardcoded value ?

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you enable the autoreload preload, it means that a modification of the ARR is taken into account only after the first cycle.

Comment: Last but not least: how do you measure this 10kHz frequency ?  By setting the LED to toggle every 1 or 2 seconds for exemple. it gives you a rough idea whether your setup is correct since you can check visually

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Yes I changed the hardcoded value. I also tried with both autoreload preload enabled and disabled. The 10 kHz frequency I measured it with an oscilloscope, so I know for sure that it didn't change.

Comment: "When I run the debugger, the UIF flag in SR register was not cleared..." Did you set up the STM32 in order that the Timer is paused during a breakpoint ? Because if not, you clear the flag and it is set again in HW immediatly (for the following count).

Comment: Perhaps your software is too slow and 10kHz is the fastest it can process the interrupts ? Try with a larger counting period, like 1s or so

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case here. The program works fine with large couting period.

Comment: Your CPU Clock is 8MHz and the prescale is 1 (0+1). The period is 128 (127+1)
Then, (8MHz / 1) / 128 = 62500 interrupts / sec, 1 interrupt every 16 us.

With a clock at 8MHz, you need a prescale of 1 and a period of 800. 
(8MHz / 1) / 800 = 10kHz

Comment: @YvonBlais My problem was I got 10kHz even if I set the period 127+1 and the prescaler is 0+1. So it seems like it takes around 100us to process an interrupt with HAL/CubeMx code. Ditching the HAL and directly modifying the timer registers and IRQHandler helps.